# windows and linux discrepancy: backslash and forward slash in c++

Tags: c++, linux, windows

In windows I have

```
std::string graphdir = projDir + "graph\\";
int mkdirsf=_mkdir(graphdir.c_str());
```

The above works quite well in windows. But in linux, you know forward slashed `/` are used. So the above will create a folder with name `graph\`. Is there an universal way to enter the correct folder without worrying about `/` or `\`?

Comment: Within some limits, Windows have supported forward slashes `/` since the DOS days. Otherwise use [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (or [Boost filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)).

Comment: Indeed, try with `/` on Windows too, and see if it works. I think it should.

Comment: Your standard library implementation will make sure that `/` works on Windows.

Comment: Its normally only the *command shell* (cmd.exe) under windows that does not understand forward slashes, the WinAPI (usually) does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might consider using forward slashes even on Windows as a directory separator. Most Windows libraries are able to convert them to backward slashes (they actually don't do a conversion, but understand them as wanted; the rest is an implementation detail)

Otherwise, notice that the C++11 (or C++14) standard don't know about "folders" (you actually mean [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)); since folders are only a GUI artefact; read e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) to check). C++17 has [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Maybe you should consider some other libraries or frameworks: [Boost](https://boost.org/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](https://qt.io/) all know how to deal with directories on common OSes (Windows, Linux, MacOSX, Android).

A more significant concern is the "drive" letter. For Windows (and even some MS-DOS) `C:/FOO/BAR.TXT` (or, using backslashes, `C:\FOO\BAR.TXT`)  and `D:/FOO/BAR.TXT` refer to different files. There is no real equivalent in Linux or MacOSX. Since [mount points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)) are more general.

At last, file hierarchy conventions (and file systems) vary widely from one OS to the other. For Linux, see [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) and [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html). Notice that [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) is also OS specific (and happens differently: in Unix systems, it is often done by [shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell); on Windows, it might be done, in every application, by some [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) like thing of the [runtime system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system)). For Linux, see also [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

BTW, perhaps you could consider using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) on your Windows machine. In lucky cases, the same *executable* could run on Linux and on Windows (under WSL), and that makes your work easier (when it is usable).

Take time to read more about [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). I recommend the [*Operating System: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) textbook (freely downloadable).

You could find useful to read more about your OS. For Linux, read [ALP](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) (or some newer book) then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html) etc... For Windows, learn the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) (I  don't know it), perhaps by starting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list).

On Linux, the API relevant to directories include [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html), [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html), [rmdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html), [getcwd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.2.html) and `closedir`, [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), etc, etc.... Be aware that a file is on Linux just an [i-node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (read [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html) and about [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)) and can be in *several* directories (or none), see [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html). AFAIU, this makes a *huge* difference with Windows.

PS. I never used Windows, and never coded for it.

Comment: "Most Windows libraries are able to convert them to backward slashes." I don't think there is a need to convert them in the first place. Even the lowest level functions treat them equally.

Comment: DOS and CP/M are happy with forward slashes since the version they introduced subdirectories.

Comment: Unless an app is running in Windows 10 with long-path support enabled both at the system level and in the application manifest, then path normalization in the runtime library is limited to `MAX_PATH`. That's 259 characters, or 247 when creating a directory (with space for an 8.3 filename). Another reason to bypass normalization is to avoid quirky rules such as DOS devices in every directory, regardless of extension (e.g. "nul.txt") and to allow names with trailing spaces and dots. Skipping normalization requires a "\\?\" local-device path, which can only use backslash as the path separator.

Comment: Also the [shell path API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shlwapi-path), which is widely used, doesn't understand forward slashes at all.

Comment: One also has to consider, that most Windows programs interpret forward slashes as introduction of command-line arguments. E. g. if you call a child processes like "some.exe /mylocalpath/subdir" it might treat the 2nd argument as a command-line flag named "/mylocalpath/subdir" instead of treating it as a path argument.

Comment: that ALP(advanced linux programming) link is broken :( you can only view copyright info after clicking...