# Why does Python seem to take Unix-style paths when running in Windows?

Tags: python, path, delimiter

This code seems to work, and I am not sure why:

```
if current_os == "Linux":
    path_to_my_dll = '../bin/lib_my_lib.so'  # I only work with 64-bit Linux
else:
    if (systemSize == 64):
        path_to_my_dll = '../bin/my_lib_64.dll'
    else:
        path_to_my_dll = '../bin/my_lib_32.dll'

my_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(path_to_my_dll)
```

I am not sure why this works.  Is LoadLibrary just smart enough to deal with it?

Comment: *Windows* takes Unix-style directory separators in most APIs.

Comment: Because it was designed that way to make it's code more portable and easier to write.

Comment: Then why all the effort put into Python's pathlib, if it isn't even really needed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334046/windows-and-linux-discrepancy-backslash-and-forward-slash-in-c

It looks like the Win API can deal with them.  Only cmd.exe has a problem.

Comment: "Then why all the effort put into Python's pathlib, if it isn't even really needed?" - pathlib is not a giant directory separator handling library.